# how to load django settings for celery app

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

This is my tree (hidding all the unnecesary stuff):

```
src/
├─ api/
│  ├─ app1/
│  │  ├─ tasks.py
│  │  ├─ models.py
│  ├─ celeryworker/
│  │  ├─ celery.py
│  ├─ settings.py
│  ├─ urls.py
├─ manage.py
├─ setup.py
```

And then this is my celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'api.settings')

app = Celery('portal')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

when I am trying to run this app:

```
cd src/api
celery -A celeryworker worker --loglevel=INFO
```

I am getting:

```
 ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
```

moreover, printing `print(app.conf)` doesn't seem to be setting any of my CELERY_ settings that I have specified in `src/api/settings.py`
How can I make my celery worker read the Django settings properly?

Comment: What do the celery settings in `settings.py` look like?

Comment: :facepalm: I was missing some important settings in settings.py. this comment made me realize that, thanks.